# Error: unrecognized arguments: --browser chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, cross-browser

> When i try to run python automation script for different browser through terminal window by using below command line:

```
pytetest -s -v testcases/test_login.py --browser chrome
```

> Where test_login the main python file,Below is the code:

```
class Test_001_Login:
   baseURL = ReadConfig.getApplicationURL()
   username = ReadConfig.getUseremail()
   password = ReadConfig.getPassword()
   logger = LogGen.loggen()


   def test_loginpage(self, setup):
            
            self.driver = setup
            self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
            self.logger.info("URL iS loaded successfully")
            self.driver.maximize_window()
            self.lp = LoginPage(self.driver)
            self.lp.setUserName(self.username)
            self.logger.info("username   entered successfully")
            self.lp.setPassword(self.password)
            self.logger.info("password   entered successfully")
            self.lp.clickLogin()
            self.logger.info("clicked on login button")
            self.driver.close()
```

> Below is the conftest code:

```
 @pytest.fixture()
    def setup(browser):
    
    if browser == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver1\chromedriver.exe")
         
        
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver1\chromedriver.exe")
    return driver

    def pytest_adoption(parser):
        parser.adoption("--browser")


    @pytest.fixture()
    def browser(request):
        return request.config.getoption("--browser")
```

**Below is the screenshot of the error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNTGj.png)

Comment: Is it typo in question, or is this copied from real conftest? Instead of "adopotion" there should be "addoption"

Comment: After updating to addoption it looks good thanks @Zenek